# Correlation methods in WCF workflow application with state machine

Tags: wcf, workflow, correlation

Can anyone let me know how to set correlation handle and correlation initilizers in a WCF workflow service appliction project. I want to set the correlation value as the pid (one of the input parameters of recevie activity). Can anyone please help me for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved under the following link

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wfprerelease/thread/6a7d9069-d5a7-4410-b5dd-16325d0d8dc9